# SuperCSV: BigInteger to String with variable Decimal Places

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, supercsv

I'm writing a CSV file using the [**SuperCSV**](https://github.com/super-csv/super-csv) package. I'm writing my beans using `CsvDozerBeanWriter`. In my beans I have a `BigInteger` value and I want to write the csv file to a variable number of decimal places (It is `8` for now).

My `CellProcessor` looks like this:

```java
     final CellProcessor[] processors = new CellProcessor[]{
                new Optional(),
                new ConvertNullTo("none"),
                new ConvertNullTo("none"),
                new ConvertNullTo("none"),
                new Optional(new FmtNumber("#####.########")), //doesn't do anything
                new Optional(),
                new Optional(),
                new Optional(),
        };
```

The value `-118700000000` should be present in the csv as `-1187.00000000`.

Does anyone have an idea?

Answer (score 0):

`-118700000000` is not the same value as `-1187.00000000` (with the decimal point there, it would be written as -1187.0 x 10<sup>8</sup>)

`FmtNumber` (and [`DecimalFormat`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html) which it uses to format the numbers) don't modify the value, only format it.

If you truly want to modify the value, you'll have to write your own processor.